# UIAlertController Title Color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, uialertcontroller

How can I change UIAlertController title color for iOS version above 12?

Below code works only for ios Version below 13 :-

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15), //your font here
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()
    ])
    
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "",  preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in
}

alert.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: its works fine for me in ios 14.3

Comment: I wouldn't use that code since it's using private properties. Tomorrow it could not work, and even crash. Be careful with that.